# Return multiple results of column-to-matrix operations within a data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a `data.table` with multiple categorical variables for which I would like to create contrast (or "dummy") variables along with many more numerical variables which I would like to simply pass by reference.

**Example dataset**:

```
library('data.table')
d <- data.table(1:3,          # there are lots of numerics, so I want to avoid copying
                letters[1:3], # convert these to factor then dummy variable
                10:12, 
                LETTERS[24:26])
# >d
#    V1 V2 V3 V4
# 1:  1  a 10  X
# 2:  2  b 11  Y
# 3:  3  c 12  Z
```

**The desired result** looks like:

```
>dummyDT(d)
    V1 V3 V2.b V2.c V4.Y V4.Z
 1:  1 10    0    0    0    0
 2:  2 11    1    0    1    0
 3:  3 12    0    1    0    1
```

which can be produced with:

```
# this does what I want but is slow and inelegant and not idiomatic data.table
categorToMatrix <- function(x, name_prefix='Var'){
  # set levels in order of appearance to avoid default re-sort by alpha
  m <- contrasts(factor(x, levels=unique(x))) 
  dimnames(m) <- list(NULL, paste(name_prefix, colnames(m), sep='.') )
  m
}
dummyDT <- function(d){
  toDummy <- which(sapply(d, function(x) is.factor(x) | is.character(x)))
  if(length(toDummy)>0){
    dummyComponent <- 
      data.table(
        do.call(cbind, lapply(toDummy, function(j) {
            categorToMatrix(d[[j]], name_prefix = names(d)[j])
          } )
         )
      )
    asIs <- (1:ncol(d))[-toDummy]
    if(length(asIs)>0) {
      allCols <- cbind(d[,asIs,with=FALSE], dummyComponent)
    } else allCols <- dummyComponent
  } else allCols <- d
  return(allCols)
}
```

(I do not care about maintaining original column ordering.)

**I have tried** in addition to the above, the approach of splitting each matrix into a list of columns, as in:

```
# split a matrix into list of columns and keep track of column names
# expanded from @Tommy's answer at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6821395/2573061
splitMatrix <- function(m){
  setNames( lapply(seq_len(ncol(m)), function(j) m[,j]), colnames(m) )
}

# Example:
splitMatrix(categoricalToMatrix(d$V2, name_prefix='V2'))
# $V2.b
# [1] 0 1 0
# 
# $V2.c
# [1] 0 0 1
```

which works for an individual column, but then when I try to `lapply` to multiple columns, these lists get somehow coerced into string-rows and recycled, which is baffling me:

```
dummyDT2 <- function(d){
  stopifnot(inherits(d,'data.table'))

  toDummy <- which(sapply(d, function(x) is.factor(x) | is.character(x)))

  if(length(toDummy)>0){
     dummyComponent <- d[, lapply(.SD, function(x) splitMatrix( categorToMatrix(x) ) ) , 
                                  .SDcols=isChar]
     asIs <- (1:ncol(d))[-toDummy]
     if(length(asIs)>0) {
        allCols <- cbind(d[,asIs,with=FALSE], dummyComponent)
     } else allCols <- dummyComponent
  } else allCols <- d
  return(allCols)
}
dummyDT2(d)
# V1 V3    V2
# 1:  1 10 0,1,0
# 2:  2 11 0,0,1
# 3:  3 12 0,1,0
# Warning message:
#   In data.table::data.table(...) :
#   Item 2 is of size 2 but maximum size is 3 (recycled leaving remainder of 1 items)
```

I then tried wrapping `splitMatrix` with `data.table()` and got an amusingly laconic error message.

I know that functions like `caret::dummyVars` exist for `data.frame`.  I am trying to create a `data.table` optimized version.

**Closely related question:** [How to one-hot-encode factor variables with data.table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39905820/how-to-one-hot-encode-factor-variables-with-data-table)

But there are two differences: I do not want full-rank dummy variables (because I'm using this for regression) but rather contrast variables (`n-1` of these for `n` levels) and I have multiple numeric variables that I do *not* want to OHE.

Comment: @eddi this is different because I do not want full-rank dummy variables (because I'm using this for regression) but rather contrast variables (n-1 of these for n levels) and I have multiple numeric variables that I do not want to OHE.

Comment: I can reopen, but it's a minor modification of the answers there

Comment: @eddi it is a couple of minor modifications, I can self answer, but thanks for reopening.  Also, unless you already know what "one hot encoding" is, that question is not very searchable (and is one very specific use case).

Comment: sure, go for it