# Add a data.table column that tells whether one of C other columns contain some value

Tags: r, data.table

Say I have a `data.table` where C columns hold discrete values among N possible values:

```
set.seed(123)
datapoints = data.table(replicate(3, sample(0:5, 4, rep=TRUE)))
print(datapoints)
   V1 V2 V3
1:  1  5  3
2:  4  0  2
3:  2  3  5
4:  5  5  2
```

(here C=3 and N=5)

I want to add N columns, each containing `TRUE` if one of the C columns contains the Nth value, `FALSE` otherwise:

```
   V1 V2 V3  has0  has1  has2  has3  has4  has5
1:  1  5  3 FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
2:  4  0  2  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
3:  2  3  5 FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
4:  5  5  2 FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

I have tried this:

```
for (value in 0:5) {
  datapoints <- datapoints[, (paste("has", value, sep="")) := (value %in% .SD), .SDcols = c("V1", "V2", "V3")]
}
```

The columns are added but filled with `FALSE`:

```
   V1 V2 V3  has0  has1  has2  has3  has4  has5
1:  1  5  3 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
2:  4  0  2 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
3:  2  3  5 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
4:  5  5  2 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

It seems to me that the code would work if I replaced `.SD` with a reference to the current row (instead of the whole table), but I don't know how to do that.

What is an efficient way of adding these columns?

Comment: Please post some data that we can use to replicate the error and help you better.

Comment: I added a reproducible example.

Comment: Related: [How to one-hot-encode factor variables with data.table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39905820/how-to-one-hot-encode-factor-variables-with-data-table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way

```
library(data.table)

# sample data
set.seed(123)
datapoints = data.table(replicate(3, sample(0:5, 4, rep=TRUE)))

# find if value exists
for(value in 0:5) {
  datapoints[, paste("has", value, sep="") := apply(.SD, 1, function(x) any(x %in% value)), .SDcols = c("V1", "V2", "V3")]
}

datapoints
#>    V1 V2 V3  has0  has1  has2  has3  has4  has5
#> 1:  1  5  3 FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
#> 2:  4  0  2  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
#> 3:  2  3  5 FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
#> 4:  5  5  2 FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

To make is more flexible you can also replace `any(x %in% value)` with `sum(x %in% value)` to get how many times that value appears per row. For the same example

```
# find how many times a value exists
for(value in 0:5) {
  datapoints[, paste("has", value, sep="") := apply(.SD, 1, function(x) sum(x %in% value)), .SDcols = c("V1", "V2", "V3")]
}

datapoints
#>    V1 V2 V3 has0 has1 has2 has3 has4 has5
#> 1:  1  5  3    0    1    0    1    0    1
#> 2:  4  0  2    1    0    1    0    1    0
#> 3:  2  3  5    0    0    1    1    0    1
#> 4:  5  5  2    0    0    1    0    0    2
```

And of course, you can still use your `.SDcols` if you only want a subset of columns.